# Algorithm for comparing chars in strings

Tags: c#, linq

How do I check if two words have a common char?

ex. : "word" and "letter" have common "r"

"word" and "email" haven't any common chars

This code is wrong because if two words have 2 common chars I get 4 in the result

```
int numberOfCommonChars = (from c1 in word1.ToCharArray()
                           from c2 in word2.ToCharArray()
                           where c1 == c2
                           select c1).Count();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code isn't working becasue using multiple `from` clauses creates a full outer join

You need to use [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx):

```
int commonCount = word1.Intersect(word2).Count();
```

Although it doesn't show in IntelliSense, `String` implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so you don't need to call `ToCharArray()`.

Note that this will only count each character once, so if both strings contain the same character twice, this will only count it once.

If you want to count multiple occurrences, use the following code:

```
var commonChars = word1.Intersect(word2);
var commonCount = commonChars.Sum(c => Math.Min(
    word1.Count(q => q == c), 
    word2.Count(q => q == c)
));
```

Comment: it doesn't work properly.

ex.

string word1 = "wow";
string word2 = "how";

it gives me 2 in result

Comment: Yes; what do you expect it to give?

Comment: I expect 1 because, they have one similar word. "How" has only one 'W'

Comment: You're forgetting that they both have an `o`.

Comment: wOW and hOW - Two letters in common.

Answer (score 0):

```
int numberOfCommonChars = (from c1 in word1.ToCharArray()
                            from c2 in word2.ToCharArray()
                            where c1 == c2
                            select c1).Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: string word1 = "wonderful";
string word2 = "wow";

gives 2 in result